# Increase Timer interval

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, time, timer, increment

I have a timer that calls the function 'bottleCreate' from 500 to 500 miliseconds. But I want that time to increase during the game (getting faster the creation of the bottles, and the game gets more difficult). But I don't know how to increase that variable inside new Timer. Thanks

```
   interval=500;
   var my_timer=new Timer(interval);
    my_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, bottleCreate);
    my_timer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the game to get faster, so the variable needs to **decrease**, because less time between function calls will make it faster.

According to the [Documentation of the Timer Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) you can use the delay variable to change the interval speed.

So, to make it faster, you could simply write

```
my_timer.delay -= 50;
```

Each time you do this, the function call will be called 50 ms faster.

Be aware though, going beneath 20ms will cause problems, according to the Documentation.

Furthermore, each time you manipulate the `delay` variable, the timer will restart completely, with the same repeat count you use at initialization.

Comment: my_timer.delay -= 50; would be enough.

Comment: but this works withought any loop? it works just like that every second?

Comment: I don't understand your question? What loop? the function that is being called every n ms? Well yes, this works without the loop having started, you can manipulate the delay before you start the loop.